# JSON viewer plugin for android studio?

Tags: android-studio

Please help me to find a JSON viewer plugin for android studio like Eclipse JSON Editor plugin.

I tried both JSONFormatter & JSON online viewer, but not working like Eclipse **JSON Editor Plugin**.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

1) Open a new scratch buffer (`Ctrl + Shift + A` and enter "scratch buffer").

2) Paste your json into the scratch buffer

3) Change the file language to Json (`Ctrl + Shift + A` and enter "change file language")

4) Reformat Code (`Ctrl + Alt + L`)

Comment: 1) and 3) can merge to New Scratch File(mac CMD+Shift+N) then select JSON

Comment: Ctrl+shift+n also if someone looking for other keymap @lukle thanks for this important one!!!

Comment: on mac, i had to use Cmd+Shift+A to create new scratch buffer & change language to json. to reformat it was Cmd+Alt+L

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution by creating a file with an extension of `.json` inside your project. Then paste the unaligned json content in this file, then press align keys(Keys combination may vary based on your Android studio Keymap. For me `Ctrl + Alt + L`). That's all json data is aligned with indents.

Answer (score 3):

For all the InelliJ IDE's you can install [this](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9679-json-viewer) plugin.

Steps to install the plugin in Android Studio on Mac

1. Click on **Android Studio** from top left corner
2. Click on **Preference**
3. Click on **Plugins**
4. Click on **Browse repositories**  from bottom bar
5. From top search bar search **JSON Viewer**
6. Click on **install** and **restart** the Android Studio
7. Size of the plugin is just 127.2KB

**How it use in Android Studio**

[image]

**It looks something like this**  [image]

Answer (score 2):

1. `Ctrl + Alt + Shift + Ins` -> Choose JSon.
2. Paste JSON
3. `Ctrl + Alt + Shift + R`

Answer (score 0):

You can just right click `.json` file in you project and find "Mark as JSON Schema".

Answer (score 0):

In the version of Android Studio Flamingo, there is a great option that is through Scratch. Path: File + New + Scratch File + JSON. In this way, it is possible to format the JSON, hierarchize it, and be notified if any parameter is incorrect or missing.[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNsb8.jpg)